# Flask Restful RequestParser Does Not Take Arguments From URL

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a project. Everything is awesome on my local device. But on remote server, where it should be run, RequestParser does not take any arguments/parameters in the URL.

Example:

```
class Example(Resource):
    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('foo1')
        parser.add_argument('foo2')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        return jsonify({'foo1': args['foo1'], 'foo2': args['foo2']})
```

The `args['foo1']` and `args['foo2']` will always `null` even I call `/example?foo1=a&foo2=b`
but this is only happen on my remote server. Any thought or solution? Thanks

Comment: what's the complete URL?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, here is the complete link `https://api.sikomo.id/example`. Its only accept `foo1` and `foo2` parameters

Comment: Please add all the relevant code in the question. It’s not possible to tell the error with the four lines of code you have provided.

Comment: There you go, I have edited my question. It runs perfectly on my laptop

Comment: You said in your question, "even I add /example?foo1=a&foo2=b but this is only happen on my remote server". What does it mean? Does it work on your remote server? Are you trying without /example?foo1=a&foo2=b?

Comment: Have you try the link?  The return is just displaying `foo1` and `foo2` value in JSON format. It doesn't work on my remote server. I tried `/example`, I tried `/example?foo1=a&foo2=b` the return is same. `foo1` and `foo2` is null

Comment: Trying specifying args location, like so: `parser.add_argument('foo1', location='args')`. Generally, unspecified location means that parser would allow args from all locations possible, but still worth a try

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But sadly, that was my code when I got this issue. And then I tried delete args location and it couldn't help. But thanks